# Manage Escalated privileges in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have created a permission policy from here

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-permission-boundaries/

The problem I am facing: I am starting a new project and know my developers need a few AWS services, EC2, Lambda, RDS etc.

With the attached policy, they are not able to create Roles so not able to spin up new services.

How can I enable them to create and modify Roles for respective services only and avoid escalated privilege?

The error I am getting

```
 authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole on resource:
```

Comment: Do you understand what a permission boundary is and do you understand the policies in the linked post? They are allowed CreateRole only if they specify the PermissionBoundary during role creation. Or are the users simply missing a iam:CreateRole ?

Comment: @luk2302 , yes I understand to test from a root user account 
1- I created a user test_permission_boundry and attached a permission boundary
2- Logged in as and when I do any operation I am:Create user I get an error test_permission_boundry is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateUser on resource:<username> I have permission boundry set for the test_permission_boundry user.  I should be able to create a user because the condition says DenyUserAndRoleCreationWithOutPermBoundary

Comment: You also need to attach permissions / a policy granting the user some permissions. The permissions boundary does not grant any permissions, it just makes sure what the user does does not exceed a set of actions.

Comment: Ahhh ... I need to assign permission boundary while creating a new user as well !! I think I missed this step